# Datagridview ComboBoxCell set default value?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, combobox

I have a datagridview with lots of data, and when I add a new line, the first column's last row creates a new ComboBoxCell which contain four items. But I can't set the default value ("DropDown") for the combobox. Every time I must manually select "DropDown". What is the solution?

```
 DataGridViewComboBoxCell dgvCell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
 dgv[1, dgv.Rows.Count - 1] = dgvCell;

 string[] controltype = {"DropDown", "CheckBoxList", "ListControl", "Tree" };
 dgvCell.DataSource = controltype;
```

Comment: what that line stand for : dgv[1, dgv.Rows.Count - 1] = dgvCell;

Comment: Add comboboxcell to datagridview's last row first column.

Comment: A line like `dgvCell.Value = controltype[0];` doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void dataGridView_DefaultValuesNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[4].Value = "DropDown";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

it,s easy,If you have a ComboBox Column in your DataGrid View and you want to know what is the selected index of the combo box, then you need to do this:
1. Handle the EditingControlShowing event of DataGrid View. In this event handler, check if the current column is of our interest. Then we create a temporary ComboBox object and get the selected index:

Code

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender,
DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0)
{
// Check box column
ComboBox comboBox = e.Control as ComboBox;
comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
}
}

void comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
int selectedIndex = ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedIndex;
MessageBox.Show("Selected Index = " + selectedIndex);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try :

```
if(!isPostBack)
  {
   dgvCell.SelectedItem=controltype[0].toString(); 
  }
```