# How to set Default ComboBox Selected Value for a DataGridView?

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

I have a DataGridView in which I have a ComboBox column. The problem is by default there is always a blank value selected in a combobox but I want to ensure that default value is always some value which is a member or combobox.

```
If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0 Then


            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
                'row.Cells("ColDrCr").Value = "Debit"
                If row.Cells("ColDrCr").Value.ToString().Trim = "Credit" Then
                    result += Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells("ColAmount").Value)
                End If
                If row.Cells("ColDrCr").Value.ToString().Trim = "Debit" Then
                    result1 += Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells("ColAmount").Value)
                End If
            Next
            txtTotal.Text = result1 - result
        End If
```

As you can see I am checking weather the selected combobox value is Debit or Credit. But when a new row is added to the DataGridView it is always blank which I want to prevent. I want to set the default value to Debit or Credit.
I tried `ColDrCr.DefaultCellStyle. = "Credit"` but it did not work because it only displays the text as Credit but when you check the value of `row.Cells("ColDrCr").Value.ToString().Trim = "Debit"` it returns null

I will accept answers in C# as well if they can be converted to vb using online tools.

Comment: I think this will solve you question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090286/datagridview-comboboxcell-set-default-value?rq=1][1], You can use "http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/" for converting c# to vb.net


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090286/datagridview-comboboxcell-set-default-value?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `DataSet` or a `DataTable` as a `DataSource` of your `DataGridView` you can set the default value for a column.

For example:

```
YourDataTable.Columns("ColDrCr").DefaultValue = "Debit"
```

Answer (score 0):

The Simplest way is updating the DataTable properties just before its bound to. However you may not be able to call DataTable properties as methods as this may throw errors. The solution is to perceive them as arrays.

Instead of this

```
dataTable.Columns("ColDrCr").DefaultValue = "Credit"
```

Use this

```
dataTable.Columns["ColDrCr"].DefaultValue = "Credit"
```